# AngularJS. Разрешение зависимостей

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Имеются фабрики **a**, **b** и **c**, использующие данные метода getResources фабрики **r** в своих методах:

```
/* Factory r */
function r() {

    var api = {
        restAPI: {}
        getResources: getResources
    }

    return api;

    /** Получает объект с REST API
     */
    function getResources() {
        return $http({url: 'path'})
            .then(function(data){
                api.restAPI = data
            })
    }
}

/* Factory a */
function a(r) {

    var api = {
        data: {}
        getProject: getProject
    }

    return api;

    /** Получает инфу о проекте, используя данные(url) из фабрики r
     */
    function getProject() {
        return $http({url: r.restAPI})
            .then(function(data) {
                api.data = data
            })
    }
}

/* Factory b */
function b(r) {...}

/* Factory c */
function c(r) {...}
```

Каким образом можно грамотно организовать цепочку загрузки, так, чтобы сначала загружались данные метода фабрики **f**, а потом методы других фабрик, использующих эти данные?

Понимаю что это промисы, но хочется знать о наиболее эффективных паттернах с конкретными примерами.

Comment: нужен пример вашего кода. что за `getResource` как его используют, что он возвращает

Comment: @Grundy добавил

Comment: `getResources` может быть вызвана несколько раз и венуть разные данные?

Comment: @Grundy нет, напротив, это издержка архитектуры. Мы должны получить в getResources все необходимые урлы и дальше их использовать в проекте где угодно.
Но по сути там может быть все что угодно, не только урлы. Вопрос именно в красивом оформлении зависимостей

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто возвращать Promise и использовать сразу их, примерно так:

```
function r() {
    var api = {
        restAPI: $http({url: 'path'})
    }

    return api;
}

function a(r) {

    var api = {
        data:  r.restAPI.then(
            function(d){
                return $http({url: d}); // Ну или поле объекта, смотря что отправляется
            })
    }

    return api;
}
```